# CSS - Apply style to last element being not of a certain type

Tags: css, polymer-3.x

## Question

I want to apply a style to the last child of an element that is **NOT** of a certain type.

Please do not confuse with: the last element **IF** it is not of a certain type.

## Example

```
<div class="container>
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <span>Child 3</span>
  <template></template>
  <span>Child 4</span>
  <template></template>
</div>
```

In this case I want to apply the style to the last element that is not of type `<template>` (would be *Child 4* in this case).

Please be aware that `:nth-last-child(2)` is not applicable, because there could be potentially more `<template>` elements.

## What I tried (and did not work)

```
.container > :not(template):last-child {
  // Style here
}

.container > :last-child:not(template) {
  // Style here
}
```

---

Thank you already!

## EDIT - It seems my question was to abstract, so I will be more concrete.

I want to have a generic spacing class (Applying this to a container will simply add a space between the items):

```css
.vertical-spacing>* {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.vertical-spacing> :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.vertical-spacing> :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* For better visibility of example */

.vertical-spacing {
  background: #ff0000
}

.vertical-spacing>* {
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-spacing">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <div>Child 3</div>
</div>
```

I am doing a project in *Polymer 3.0* where you can use a conditional template that will be visible only under certain conditions:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="condition">
  <div>Content</div>
</template>
```

If the `<template>` is the last child in the spacing container (or multiple templates are the last children, number is not fixed) and the condition is false, the result is that the content of the `<template>` is hidden, nevertheless the `<template>` element itself is still present. By consequence there is a useless space at the end of the container:

```css
.vertical-spacing>* {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.vertical-spacing> :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.vertical-spacing> :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* For better visibility of example */

.vertical-spacing {
  background: #ff0000
}

.vertical-spacing>div {
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-spacing">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <temlate>
    <div style="display: none">Content</div>
  </temlate>
</div>
<div style="background: #0000ff; color: white">Stuff after container: there is a margin on top as you can see</div>
```

I now want to be able to apply the style that removes the margin to the last element in the container that is not a `<template>`.

Comment: IMHO if styles become so complicated and contain so strange logic it's time to rewrite your markup. And I believe it's not possible to do what you want using only css.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: Not sure about polymer3, could we use java script or jQuery there?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.vertical-spacing>* {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.vertical-spacing> :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.vertical-spacing> :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* For better visibility of example */

.vertical-spacing {
  background: #ff0000
}

.vertical-spacing>* {
  background: #00ff00;
}


.vertical-spacing > *:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom:0;

}
span{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-spacing">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <p>'p' tag child </p>
  <span>'span' tag child </span>
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <span>'span' tag child </span>
  <template>
    <div style="display: none">Content</div>
  </template>
</div>
<div style="background: #0000ff; color: white">Stuff after container: there is a margin on top as you can see</div>
```

Simply write

```
.vertical-spacing > *:last-of-type { margin-bottom:0;}
```

I think this will solve your margin issue.

Comment: Nearly! This will not work if you do have different children, e.g. an additional `<span>` instead of only `<div>`s. Then there will be no space between those children.

Comment: @JDC - This will work for all the elements. span is not working because it is an inline element. Give display:inline-block to span and see the margin. Please see the snippet. I have added different elements

Comment: @JDC - I understood the issue. Let me try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/) that neatly explains the difference between `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` which is probably the reason `:last-of-type` will work but `:last-child` will not.

`:nth-of-type` looks at any and all child elements of a parent but `:nth-child` works a bit differently and doesn't always work if you have different types of child elements like you do here.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If you want to exclude the template tag/tags I would just put it outside the div that the other elements are in, and put that div and those templates in one big div

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS pseudo-class `:last-of-type` :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y21qL8jz/

Comment: `Child 4` is red, but it should not be.

Comment: I targeted the last `<p>` and the last `<div>` so yes.  I read below that he want to apply this to all elements except `<template>` so i gave him an example.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example what you are asking I guess, to see the result I put a div in the end, please remove the div and you will see that its not affecting the span, You can put your template in place of span in CSS, Remove and add div to see the results

```css
.container > *:last-child:not(span) {
  font-size: 48px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <span>Child 3</span>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <span>Child 4</span>
  <br>
  <span>dwdw</span>
  <div>atul</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what code is doing dear, if its last item is span, in JDC's code it will be template, then it will not affect the item at all, otherwise it will, that's what question is asking

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. If I exclude `span`, I want the last child that is not a span to be formatted. In my case I exclude `template`, so I want the last child that is not a `template` to be formatted.

Comment: Ohh, My bad then. I misunderstood. let me figure it out if something can be done in this case

Answer (score -1):

you may try:

```
span:last-of-type {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Bu what if I want it to be applied to all elements **EXCEPT** `<template>`? SO `div`, `span`, etc.?

Comment: I believe you will have to target them individually e.g. ```span:last-of-type```, ```div:last-of-type```, etc. Unfortunately, **CSS** is not that smart yet to be able to figure things out.